# Rails + ActiveRecord - how to fetch word where column is not true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, boolean

I am running this application on Heroku, where is used PostgreSQL and I am trying something like this:

```
Model.where('column.something = ? AND listings.status IS NOT ?', 'something', true)
```

or

```
Model.where('column.something = ? AND listings.status != ?', 'something','t')
```

but neither one version doesn't work.
I am trying to get all records, where in the column **status** is not the value **true** (the column type is boolean).

Thanks

Comment: Strange behaviour.. Please try with Model.where("column.something = '#{something}' AND listings.status IS NOT true") OR Model.where("column.something = '#{something}' AND listings.status IS NOT 1")

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
Model.where('column.something = ? AND listings.status != ?', 'something', true)
```

or

```
Model.where('column.something = ? AND listings.status <> ?', 'something', true)
```

but only if both columns `something` and `status` are the same table. If not, you have to add `.joins(:listings)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Model.where.not(column: 'something')
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions

Comment: This exists from Rails 4.0.0 so may not be a solution.